# Chat banner escapes sidebar

Tags: bug, design, chat, sidebar

Today on sidebar, Worldbuilding SE:

[image: Long chat link escapes sidebar to the right, going onto its own adventure]

As you can see, chat room name turned out to be too long and unsplittable due to question link and decided to run out of sidebar. I think that long links can be safely broken into parts by splitting after slashes.